# Open Port on Specific Windows User Account?

Tags: windows

Suppose I have setup two windows user accounts on a remote machine. If I open port 5555 in account "A" will this automatically open port 5555 on account B? Essentially, what I'm asking is: Is the port specific to the windows user account or the machine (or IP)?

The reason I ask is bec I want to setup selenium to connect to remote machine accessing two different windows user accounts. I hope to connect to account A via port 5555 and to account B via port 6666 but this will only work if indeed the two users accounts have their own port system.

Thanks

Comment: You cant have two applications listening on the same port. You also cant have two users on the same pc at the same time. The port is specific to the windows instance and IP

Answer (score 0):

A port is based on the IP address of the machine - thus it's common for all users on the machine.

If your users are aware of multiple IPs that you allocate for the machine, you can have them bind to specific IP/port combinations. But this also doesn't identify the user.

Network packages (that are routed to your machine) don't know anything about user account names, they just carry IP/port destinations. That's the limitation that you'll have to deal with.

Comment: So am I correct to assume that if I wanted to connect to a specific instance of Selenium (i.e, running on a specific windows user account) I'd need to basically connect to the port Selenium is listening on? In other words, when I start Selenium from within windows acc A and tell it to listen on port 5555 I'd just connect to port 5555 and when launching Selenium it would run automatically from within this windows account?

Comment: Exactly like that. Correct.